# How to best creating a horizontal sliding in from right multi level ul li menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have nested ul li menu I want it displayed as shown in this image. Users are able to click through like in mobile menu. You click and the next item which is the li child of the .submenu replaces the previous item.

[image]
When clicked, the next level menu slides in from right and replaces the previous item.
Here is my current structure:

```
<ul class="list-style-none">
   <li class="li-select">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-8">
            Toys
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-4 text-right"><i class="w-icon-angle-right li-select"></i></div>
      </div>
      <ul class="submenu" style="">
         <li class="li-select">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-8">
                  Baby Toys and Scrabbles
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-4 text-right"><i class="w-icon-angle-right li-select"></i></div>
            </div>
            <ul class="submenu">
               <li class="li-select">
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-md-8">
                        Used Baby Toys and Scrabbles
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-md-4 text-right"><i class="w-icon-angle-right li-select"></i></div>
                  </div>
                  <ul class="submenu">
                     <li class="li-select">
                        <div class="row">
                           <div class="col-md-8">
                              Cheap Toys
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-md-4 text-right"><i class="w-icon-angle-right li-select"></i></div>
                        </div>
                     </li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="li-select">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-8">
            Cars
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-4 text-right"><i class="w-icon-angle-right li-select"></i></div>
      </div>
      <ul class="submenu">
         <li class="li-select">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-8">
                  Jeep
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-4 text-right"><i class="w-icon-angle-right li-select"></i></div>
            </div>
            <ul class="submenu">
               <li class="li-select">
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-md-8">
                        Used jeep
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-md-4 text-right"><i class="w-icon-angle-right li-select"></i></div>
                  </div>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

And the JQuery should be:

```
$('.li-select').on('click', function(e){
            $(this).closest('li').find('ul.submenu').first().slideToggle("fast");
           
        });
```

Comment: I suspectthe primary issue is your attempt to use `closest()`. This will move up in the hierarchy to find a parent element that matches. Removing this should help, and instead use: `$(this).find('ul.submenu').first().slideToggle("fast");`

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example.

```js
$(document).on('click', ".li-select", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).find('ul.submenu').first().toggleClass("collapsed expanded");
});
```

```css
.list-style-none {
  list-style: none;
}

.collapsed {
  display: none;
}

.expanded {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-style-none">
  <li class="li-select">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        Toys
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 text-right"><i class="w-icon-angle-right li-select"></i></div>
    </div>
    <ul class="submenu collapsed">
      <li class="li-select">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-8">
            Baby Toys and Scrabbles
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 text-right"><i class="w-icon-angle-right li-select"></i></div>
        </div>
        <ul class="submenu collapsed">
          <li class="li-select">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-8">
                Used Baby Toys and Scrabbles
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4 text-right"><i class="w-icon-angle-right li-select"></i></div>
            </div>
            <ul class="submenu collapsed">
              <li class="li-select">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-8">
                    Cheap Toys
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-4 text-right"><i class="w-icon-angle-right li-select"></i></div>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="li-select">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        Cars
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 text-right"><i class="w-icon-angle-right li-select"></i></div>
    </div>
    <ul class="submenu collapsed">
      <li class="li-select">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-8">
            Jeep
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 text-right"><i class="w-icon-angle-right li-select"></i></div>
        </div>
        <ul class="submenu collapsed">
          <li class="li-select">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-8">
                Used jeep
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4 text-right"><i class="w-icon-angle-right li-select"></i></div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This shows a correction to the way items are selected:

```
$(this).find('ul.submenu').first()
```

In this delegated event, the matched item, `this` is the `li` element that was clicked. We then find the matched children element.

> The `stopPropagation()` method of the Event interface prevents further propagation of the current event in the capturing and bubbling phases.

See More: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation